# How to connect from Google Dialogflow to Website?

Tags: html, dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot

I am trying to use dialogflow's integration called Dialogflow messenger and the integration is at beta stage. I copied and pasted the dialogflow messenger integration into an html page on my laptop but when I run my html page the chatbot's message does not appear. Do you know how to resolve the problem?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Chatbot UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div class="container">
             <img src="img/pp.png" class="mainlogo"> 
             <h3 class="slogan">Hi, I am TrustQnABot! I will try to assist you as much as possible, try me!</h3>
        </div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/dialogflow-console/fast/messenger/bootstrap.js?v=1"></script>
<df-messenger
  intent="WELCOME"
  chat-title="TrustQnABot"
  agent-id="6f566fba-9427-4c10-ace9-7680e9a457ba"
  language-code="en"
></df-messenger>
</body>
```

Output:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkt8L.png)

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because you can't send request from your computer directly to dialogflow if you check your browser console you will se an error related with CORS. I had the same issue, for now to bypass this issue I'm using [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/) to test the Dialogflow messenger.